# How do filter out rows that contain either NaN or '-'?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe and I want to filter out all rows that have either '-' or NaN in them.  I am trying:

```
df[(~df.isin(['-'])) & (~df.isnull())]
```

but the result is:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try this, ```df.replace('-', np.NaN).dropna(how="all")```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#Drop all NaN values
#Set the "inplace" parameter to True if you want the result to be stored in the same DF
df.dropna(inplace=True)
```

A More general approach:

```
condition = df[ df['col'] == '-' ].index

# Delete rows where "condition" applies

df.drop(condition , inplace=True)
```

Also equivalent to:

```
df[df.col != '-']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df.dropna()
```

This should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of & you should be using | as the or operator.

Also, there is a .notnull() function. Just an FYI.

Replying on mobile. Hope this helps.